# hive string extraction

Tags: regex, string, hive, hiveql

I have a column which has values like https://ysd.com/ert490ghlkh/gsum

I would like to fetch all the characters after `com/` and before `/gsum`. In advance, I know how many characters to fetch after .com/ . Like I know 11 characters have to be fetched after `.com`.

I tried like

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, 'https://ysd.com/', ''), '/gsum', '')
```

It doesn't seem to be ideal because the last part `/gsum` can vary. In that case, I have to write no of case statements which is equal to unique last part.

Can anyone say how to fetch no of characters after a particular substring?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, 'https://ysd\\.com/([^/]+).*', '\\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2lull/1)

**Details**

- `https://ysd\\.com/` - a `https://ysd.com/` string
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` is a backreference to the group value that is used in the replacement pattern): any one or more chars other than `/`
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Extract group between slash:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('https://ysd.com/ert490ghlkh/gsum', '.*/(.*)/.*', '$1')
```

Result:

```
ert490ghlkh
```